# while passing php 2d array to Javascript and try to parse using json_encode() It throws uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I i try try to access passed php 2d array using json_encode function in javascript it throws the error that its an uncaught typeerror and the array is null, but if i print the contents of array in php only it is printing and having values in it. but it is not passing to javascript.

Both javascript and php are in same file.Below is simply a sample code snippet

```
 var javascript_var = echo json_encode($Php_2D_array);
 alert(javascript_var[0].OrderDate[1]); //javascript_var['OrderDate'].[1] earlier i tried to access like this because im having php variable index as a name as mentioned
```

Please help me sort out this problem

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var javascript_var = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($Php_2D_array); ?>");
 alert(javascript_var[0].OrderDate[1]);
```

First you need to convert to json and then javascript will take it as string, then you parse it in js.

Answer (score 0):

you can encode array value in javascript by using instruction

> `JSON.stringify`

if your array variable is in php then

```
var javascript_var = JSON.stringify('<?php  echo $Php_2D_array?>');
```

if your array variable is in javascript

```
var javascript_var = JSON.stringify(var_array);
```

Comment: please see my answer @sai narayanan